# Why does this program just hang?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following program:

```
static void Main(string[] args) { RunTest(); }

    private static void RunTest() {
        DoIOWorkFiveTimesAsync().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task DoIOWorkFiveTimesAsync() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            Console.WriteLine("Before: " + i);
            await DoIOWorkAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("After: " + i);
        }
    }

    private static Task DoIOWorkAsync() {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing work...");
        return new Task(() => Thread.Sleep(1500));
    }
```

I would expect to see:

```
  Before: 1
  Doing work...
  After: 1
  Before: 2
  Doing work...
  After: 2
  Before: 3
  Doing work...
  After: 3
  Before: 4
  Doing work...
  After: 4
  Before: 5
  Doing work...
  After: 5
```

But instead, it gets to:

```
Before: 1
Doing work...
```

And never gets any further. I have tried and tried to understand the async/await features in C#5, but always to no effect. Again, the explanation eludes me.

Comment: If you had a `SynchronizationContext` the result would be obvious, the blocking wait prevents the continuations from being scheduled, but as you're not setting one, this shouldn't be happening...

Comment: You should use `Task.Delay` to create a task that will be completed in X milliseconds instead of what you're doing.  Your method is blocking a thread for the duration of the wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, you returned a `Task`, but you didn't start it.

If you change your code as follows:

```
private static Task DoIOWorkAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doing work...");
    Task work = new Task(() => Thread.Sleep(1500));
    work.Start();
    return work;
}
```

It works as you would expect.

Comment: Hmm... I assumed await would start the task. Thanks.

Comment: Not if you're explicitly creating the task, I think if you define the function as `async` as you did with the `DoIOWorkFiveTimesAsync` it wraps that function in a `Task` and starts it automatically (compiler generates the necessary code).

Comment: @Motig In general, it's just a good idea to use `Task.Run` to return a task already started, and not rely on anything starting the task for you.  In early previews, await would start the task, but it no longer does, and assumes it's running.  `new Task` is almost always a bad idea...

Comment: Okay, I take your point(s), but then I still fail to see what async/await actually does for anyone. All of that code above will act exactly the same if I remove the async/await out of it.

Comment: @Motig Yes, in your example there is no point in using it. However in situations where you have a `SynchronizationContext` (like on a Form or WPF app) the main thread could be doing other work while you await. The point of async/await is so that the code before the `await` happens on the same `SynchronizationContext` (think "thread") as the code after the `await` without blocking the `SynchronizationContext` while you wait for the item to finish.

Comment: @Motig, if you were to remove the await, then your "Doing Work" would not be inside your "Before" and "After"s.  So, no, it wouldn't be the same.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is you're using `return new Task(() => Thread.Sleep(1500));` instead of `Task.Run`.

`new Task` doesn't actually start the task, which will cause the `await` to never trigger.

Instead, try:

```
private static Task DoIOWorkAsync() {
    Console.WriteLine("Doing work...");
    return Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1500));
}
```

Or, better yet:

```
private static async Task DoIOWorkAsync() {
    Console.WriteLine("Doing work...");
    await Task.Delay(1500);
}
```